# Google Analytics Integration in Expo app without ejecting

Tags: react-native, expo, google-analytics-api

I want to add the google analytics integration in my expo project. And i don't want to eject the project form expo. Is there is any solution to integrate google analytics in expo project.

i used google analytics api's endpoint for integration but it didn't work.
here is api endpoint `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect`
Please help me in that!